# Condition for roots of a biquadratic eqn. to be real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If b$^2$ >= $4ac$ for the eqn.

ax$^4$ + bx$^2 $ + c=0

Then prove that all the roots of the above eqn. will be real if

1. b<0, a>0, c>0
2. b>0, a>0, c>0

My attempt...
I substituted y=x$^2$ and then arrived at the condition D >=0 for real roots which gives me b$^2$ >= 4ac...but this condition is already mentioned in the question so how can i decide based on the signs of a b and c whether the roots are real or not?? Also is assuming y=x$^2$ correct to check if all roots of the given biquadratic are real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know $y=x^2$ is real if $b^2\ge4ac$. In fact, $y=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. If $y=x^2$, what conditions are necessary for $x$ to be real?

Comment: [-b (+-) (b^2 - 4ac)^0.5 ]/2a > 0   ie y>=0     ... right?

Comment: If yes then how do i analyse this inequality?

Comment: Right. The denominator is always positive if $a>0$, so what would make the numerator negative? Recall that $D>0$ as well, so basically you're trying to find when $-b\pm\sqrt{D}>0$.

Comment: If a>0 then -b(+-)D     should be greater than or equal to zero....this will result in two cases -b+D>0 and -b-D>0 both of which yield contradictory results.....so am i right track? If not plz guide me...

Comment: Yes. You were given 2 cases, one where $b>0$, one where $b<0$. In each case, only one root will be positive, but you're on the right track.

Comment: Ok on analysing the case b>= D.....im getting the required result that 4ac >0 ....ie a and c have same sign and hence the above two cases mentioned in the question are proved...but when i solve the second case which is D>b im getting 4ac<0 which means a and c are opposite in sign and as u said that only one root will be positive in each case so does that mean that out of four roots only two will be real??

Comment: This is how I'd look at it... If $b<0$, then $-b>0$, and so if $|b|>\sqrt{D}$, then both roots are real. If not, then only the '+' root is real. On the other hand, if $b>0$, then $-b<0$ and the '-' root is never real, and the other root is only real if $\sqrt{D}>|b|$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok got it thanks!!

Comment: Happy to help! Can you click the green check mark to show the question has been answered to your satisfaction?